# std::async and lambda function in C++ gives no associated state

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, asynchronous, lambda

I'm trying to obtain a better performance in my program by using async whenever this is convenient. My program compiles, but I get the following error every time I use a function containing async calls:

```
C++ exception with description "No associated state"
```

The way I am trying to call async with a lambda is e.g. as follows:

```
auto f = [this](const Cursor& c){ return this->getAbsIndex(c); };
auto nodeAbsIndex = std::async(f,node); // node is const Cursor&
auto otherAbsIndex = std::async(f,other); // other too

size_t from = std::min(nodeAbsIndex.get(), otherAbsIndex.get());
size_t to = std::max(nodeAbsIndex.get(), otherAbsIndex.get());
```

Signature of the function to call is as follows:

```
uint64_t getAbsIndex(const Cursor& c) const
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any hints!
Diego

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't call `get()` twice on the same future. Read documentation carefully (the part regarding `valid()`): http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get

On a side note, implicitly casting `uint64_t` to `size_t` is not good. The latter could be of smaller size.